# где поставить yield в генераторе простых чисел (из которых потом нужно выбрать счастливые)?

Tags: python-3.x

есть генератор, точнее не генератор, т.к. не стоит yield. куда его поставить? как только ни пробовал. то он ничего не выдает, то выдает None. подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n+1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if number % prime == 0:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
    return prime_numbers #да, здесь return, куда поставить yield я как раз не знаю  


for number in prime_numbers_generator(n=10000):
    print(number)
```

и потом к этому генератору нужно написать функцию-фильтр, чтобы получить только счастливые числа

```
если число имеет нечетное число цифр (например 727 или 92083),
то для вычисления "счастливости" брать равное количество цифр с начала и конца:
        727 -> 7(2)7 -> 7 == 7 -> True
        92083 -> 92(0)83 -> 9+2 == 8+3 -> True
```

сделал такой вариант:

```
def lucky_digits(string):
    middle = len(str(string)) // 2
    if middle == 0 or string[:middle] == string[-middle:]:       
        print(f'{string} - Счастливое')
    else:
        print(f'{string} - Обычное')
```

но это тоже не то...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from operator import eq

def prime_numbers_generator(n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for number in range(2, n + 1):
        for prime in prime_numbers:
            if not number % prime:
                break
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(number)
            yield number

def is_eq_sum(str_v, *slices):
    return eq(*map(lambda s: sum(map(int, s)), map(str_v.__getitem__, slices)))

def lucky_digits(v):
    str_v = str(v)
    if len(str_v) < 2:
        return True
    else:
        middle = len(str_v) // 2
        return is_eq_sum(str_v, slice(middle), slice(-middle, None))


for i in filter(lucky_digits, prime_numbers_generator(100000)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: большое спасибо!